# Django best practice combain REST API with Web application or sperate the both?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on a Project with Django backend and Flutter frontend. We have to do a Web application for the admin for adding data to the Rest framework/Database (excluding the admin panel).
My question is, should I add the web application to the existing API project, or should I start a completely new Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible to start a new project and use the same database but i think it's not a true way according to the django principles and you can simply add another app in your project for your web application.
off course you know that django-rest-framework is a library based on django framework,not an another framework!